# SailsJS Blueprint `AND` condition

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to build a query for my search page using the SailsJS blueprint routes.
I looked at the [documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language) and in the `find` [doc page](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where) and did not see any solution on how I can implement a query involving `AND` and `WHERE`.

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
where={
        "or":[
        {"partNumber": {"contains": "A B"}},
        {"description": {"contains": "A B"}},
        "and": [
        {"partNumber": {"contains": "A"}},
        {"partNumber": {"contains": "B"}},
        ],
        "and": [
        {"description": {"contains": "A"}},
        {"description": {"contains": "B"}},
        ],
    ]
}
```

Any idea on how to do this with the blueprint route api?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you have to create your own action and route to handle it.
Blueprints are useful but made for standard operations and your request is not standard/simple

Comment: I was afraid It would be that way. It seems to me like a standard request. `OR` is already implemented in the query language, so why not `AND`?

Comment: Could you maybe supply me with a demo of how can I implement this without the usage of `query()`? I've been trying for several hours now, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

var where = {}

```
       where.$or = [
               {title: {contains: "Hello"}}
               {description: {contains: "Hello World"}}
             ]

    where.$and = [
            {description: {contains: "A"}}
            ]
```